# How to apply javascript functionality to ajax inserted html

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page that requests the user to input a time via selecting the time from a pop-up.

php:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Coaching Start Time</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="timepicker" name="timepicker[]" placeholder="Enter Time" />
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* setting time */
    $("#timepicker").datetimepicker({
        format : "HH:mm"
    });
});
</script>
```

I want the possibility to select and submit multiple time values, so via ajax, I'm inserting copies of the php code into the page.

Ajax Call from main page:

```
//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
        x++; //Increment field counter
        var sd = document.getElementById("hired_date").value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                $(wrapper).append(this.responseText);
            }
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_schedule_options.php?sd=" + sd, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Relevant ajax php code:

```
echo '<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="Old">Coaching Start Time</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="timepicker" name="timepicker[]" placeholder="Enter Time" />
    </div>
</div>';
```

However, the functionality is lost because the javascript code is applied at a timing before the ajax inserts the extra html code. How can I go about applying javascript functionality to ajax inserted code?

Comment: *"via ajax, I'm inserting copies of the php code into the page."* You can't insert php code frontend. What does your response look like?

Comment: One of the ways : Trigger the related JavaScript action in the success block of the ajax return

Comment: it seems that a delegated event listener would be the way to proceed if I understood the requirements correctly but ID attributes **must** be unique so if you are adding content that duplicates ID attributes you need to redesign that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the same code after you append the response in your HTML.
And make sure you use class selector instead of id.
After this -

```
$(wrapper).append(this.responseText);
```

Add this -

```
 $(".timepicker").datetimepicker({
        format : "HH:mm"
    });
```

And input tag must contain class with timepicker i.e.

```
<input class="form-control timepicker" type="text"  id="timepicker" name="timepicker[]" placeholder="Enter Time" />
```